# Why is Laravel "remembering" this deleted route?

Tags: laravel-4, routes

I had a `route > controller > view` combination which displayed a login form in Laravel.
The form is no longer needed, so I simply deleted the code shown below.

```
// file: routes.php
Route::get('/account/sign-in', array(
    'as'    => 'account-sign-in',
    'uses'  => 'AccountController@getSignIn'
));
```

.

```
// file: AccountController.php
 public function getSignIn() {
   return View::make('account.signin');
}
```

.

```
// file: /app/views/account/signin.blade.php
```

If I enter the old URL: `/account/sign-in` in the browsers address bar I get Laravels "whoops" screen with:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

* @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
     */
    protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }
```

#### How can I prevent this exception being thrown when the old route is requested?

---

Relevant info

- Laravel version: v4.2.5
- If I enter any other route "unknown" to Laravel - it gets caught with a `App::missing();` route and redirected - with "user friendly" message
- List of routes that begin with `/account`  (there are more, list reduced for brevity)

```php
POST account/change-password  
GET|HEAD account/change-password
account/sign-out
POST account/forgot-password 
POST account/create  
 POST account/sign-in   
GET|HEAD account/forgot-password
```

What Ive tried already

- composer dump autoload

Comment: Do you have any other routes starting with `/account`? Can you post all of them. It will be because you are hitting a different route

Comment: yes lots, Ive updated question to show about half of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not remembering anything.

It is showing you a 404 error page because the route does not exist. You can see that by the exception: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

The reason is that you have a `Route::post('account/sign-in')`.

If you want to not show a 404 error page for that route - you need to keep the Route::get() - then redirect (using `return Redirect::*`) to another page from the controller - so users are automatically redirected.

Or you need to change your `Route::post('account/sign-in')` to something else.

Comment: thanks, changing `Route::post('account/sign-in')` to something else fixed it. It seems the error is triggered when a GET request is made to a route/URL that Laravel is listening for a POST request on.